# The output isn't what i expected. Can someone make me understand why is so?

Tags: java

```
public class Puzzel1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        for (byte i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(i);
            list.remove(new Integer(i));    
        }

        System.out.println("*");
        System.out.println(list.size()); 
    }
}
```

the output of this come 10 why?

Comment: What did you **expect** it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.add(i); // Here you are adding byte type
list.remove(new Integer(i)); // Here you are removing integer type
```

Answer (score 3):

after inserting the automatic boxing the code becomes:

```
public class Puzzel1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        for (byte i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(Byte.valueOf(i));
            list.remove(new Integer(i));    
        }

        System.out.println("*");
        System.out.println(list.size()); 
    }
}
```

Remove relies on the `equals` method of the elements.

and because `Byte.valueOf(i).equals(new Integer(i))` is always false the elements are never removed

Comment: And the price goes to Joshua Block who shown probably first this puzzle  .

Answer (score 2):

its becoz we are adding byte data to the the list and try to remove the integer so it doesn't remove any value from the list so when we are printing it its showing size 10.